# ASP.NET Web API 2 + Entity Framework Model First + ASP.NET Membership Provider

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So, the title says it all:

Is there a way to set up an ASP.NET web API with EF Model First and ASP.NET Membership Provider?

I decided to use the Model First because I'm migrating from a previous system using MySQL database and PHP codebehind, so it is more suitable for me to create the mapping in the visual editor according to the previous database. Also, I'm not using the same database structure as before since many unneeded features will go and new ones will come in, and the previous system was fragmented in the first place.

Comment: You're asking if it's possible to create an ASP.NET WebAPI application which uses Entity Framework?  Yes.  Yes it is possible.

Comment: If you are going to redo or manually do the mapping anyways I think it's preferable to use Code First instead

Comment: The question is not if it's possible to create WebAPI with Entity Framework. The question is if it's possible to use EF Model First with Memberships at all, since there is barely anything t be found online.

Comment: ASP.Net Membership Provider has been deprecated long time ago. Is there a reason not to use ***ASP.Net Identity 2***?

Comment: Model-first is *similarly* deprecated and will be removed entirely in EF 7 forward. See: http://cpratt.co/entity-framework-code-first-with-existing-database/

Comment: @Dracor: It's not clear what Entity Framework and the ASP.NET Membership Provider have to do with one another at all.  Doesn't the built-in membership/role provider simply interact directly with the database internally?  Where would EF be used in that scenario?  If you want to use EF to customize the membership implementation, you can create a custom provider.  That doesn't really have anything to do with EF either, other than that your custom implementation would coincidentally use EF internally.

Comment: Oh god, I just realised that EF Model First generates partial classes... '-'